# Extracting borders for cells in table with python-docx

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx

I have a project where I'm converting tables from Word documents using python-docx and am wondering if there is a way to tell if a given cell has borders on its left, right, top, and bottom. I understand that I can view the style of the table as it's presented in the UI, but if someone has made modifications to that style it's not clear to me that I can recover arbitrary border information.

Is this currently possible?

I've tried doing something like:

```
for table in document.tables:
    for row in table.rows:
        for cell in row.cells:
            tc = cell._tc
            tcPr = tc.get_or_add_tcPr()
            tcBorders = tcPr.first_child_found_in("w:tcBorders")
            etree.dump(tcBorders)
```

but unfortunately it seems that most of the time there is no w:tcBorders element. I say most of the time because I ran an example one time where I did some some elements there but they didn't have the edges where I expected them (and I haven't been able to reproduce that example after playing around with the tables in my test document).

Comment: I would recommend using `print(cell._tc.xml)` to inspect the XML for a cell you want to operate on (has known borders I suppose). From there you can possibly get some idea what is making the cell look the way it is and get some direction for what elements to extract.

Comment: Thank you @scanny. I appreciate your help and your work on the package.